# Identify distinct number of integers in a set

Tags: python, integer, set

If the input was a list of integers, how would i determine how many distinct numbers there are in one line of code using sets?

If the input was:

```
1 2 3 2 1
```

I would want an output of:

```
3
```

Sorry for the lack of knowledge, I'm trying to teach myself how to use sets in order to complete some tasks and I can't find anything online that will help me... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you even try to use a set?

Comment: Do you know what a set is?

Comment: I only know what they can be used for but i honestly have no idea how to use them... i apologise

Comment: Go to https://www.python.org/shell/, then use `set` as a function. Give it integer values and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use sets. Sets remove all duplicates from your list:

```
import itertools
n = int(input("Enter the number of inputs "))
l = list(itertools.chain(*[map(int, input().split()) for i in range(n)]))
print(len(set(l)))
```

Comment: @AntsOfTheSky glad to help!

Comment: If there were 2 separate inputs, do you know how you could take both of these in the same line of code?

Comment: @AntsOfTheSky Please see my recent edit. This new post assumes you want the entire user input to be flattened.

Answer (score 0):

A set is a collection that consists out of *unique hashable* objects. That means that you can only add an object once: once added, adding an equivalent object, will not have an impact on the set.

So the set of `1, 2, 3, 2, 1` is:

```
>>> set([1,2,3,2,1])
{1, 2, 3}
```

So you can use:

```
>>> len(set([1,2,3,2,1]))
3
```

to obtain the number of items in the set.